# Gspread do google colab e pandas

Tags: python, pandas, google, ciência-de-dados

eu comecei a usar o google colab para fazer algumas análises da empresa e ele dá a opção de ao invés de ler o arquivo csv, já ler automaticamente o arquivo existente nas planilhas do google no drive. O problema é que ele está colocando o nome das colunas como primeira linha do df. Alguém sabe como corrigir isso? O código gerado pelo colab pra essa leitura está abaixo

```
!pip install --upgrade gspread
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()

import gspread
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

gc = gspread.authorize(GoogleCredentials.get_application_default())

worksheet = gc.open('nome planilha').sheet1

# get_all_values gives a list of rows.
rows = worksheet.get_all_values()
print(rows)

# Convert to a DataFrame and render.
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows)
```

[image: Assim é como está gerando a tabela por esse código do google colab. Eu até tinha montado outro programa que eu baixava a planilha do google sheet em formato csv e fazia a leitura. O programa todo rodou corretamente. Só agora que fui implementar essa parte de código que não tá dando certo mesmo. Mas ai no google sheet tá dessa mesma forma, só que a linha 0 é o nome das colunas]

Comment: Ronaldo, bom dia! Como está organizada a planilha no google docs? Poderia colocar um print?

Comment: Coloquei o resultado que tá aparecendo no colab, mas se precisar do print do google sheet mesmo posso tirar também. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> ...
> # get_all_values gives a list of rows.
> rows = worksheet.get_all_values()
> print(rows)
> ...
> ```

Import do pandas

```
import pandas as pd
```

Uma saída é pegar a primeira linha e transformar em colunas:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows, columns = rows[0] )
```

E depois remover a primeira linha:

```
df.drop(0, axis = 0, inplace = True)
```

Outra possível saída é colocar manualmente os nomes da colunas.

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado!!

Comment: Fala Ronaldo, que bom que resolveu! Caso a resposta tenha solucionado seu problema, considere em marcar a resposta como válida(não é obrigatório mas é uma boa prática para futuros usuários com o mesmo problema). [Veja como](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyLkG.jpg). Abraço!

Answer (score -2):

No lugar de get_all_values() usa get_all_records()